# Instantsearch One hit container for multiple hits widgets

Tags: javascript, algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm currently struggling with Algolia instantsearch v1. What I'd like to accomplish is not to have multiple hits containers for each hit widget.

Here's the full code:

```
var template_fachbereiche =
    '<a href="{{url}}">'+
        '<div class="title"><strong>{{fachbereich}}</strong></div>'+
        '<div class="text">{{{_highlightResult.titel.value}}}</div>'+
    '</a>';

var template_zentren =
    '<a href="{{url}}">'+
        '<div class="title"><strong>{{fachbereich}}</strong></div>'+
        '<div class="text">{{{_highlightResult.titel.value}}}</div>';
    '</a>';

var template_experten =
    '<img src="{{profilbild}}">'+
    '<div class="text"><p><strong>{{{_highlightResult.name.value}}}</strong>{{position}}</p></div>';

var template_sprechstunden =
    '<strong>{{titel}}</strong>'+
    '<p>{{text}}</p>';

var fachbereiche = instantsearch({
    appId: appId,
    apiKey: apiKey,
    indexName: 'fachbereiche',
    searchFunction: function(helper) {
        var query = fachbereiche.helper.state.query;
        zentren.helper.setQuery(query);
        zentren.helper.search();
        sprechstunden.helper.setQuery(query);
        sprechstunden.helper.search();
        experten.helper.setQuery(query);
        experten.helper.search();
        helper.search();
    }
});

var zentren = instantsearch({
    appId: appId,
    apiKey: apiKey,
    indexName: 'zentren'
});

var experten = instantsearch({
    appId: appId,
    apiKey: apiKey,
    indexName: 'experten'
});

var sprechstunden = instantsearch({
    appId: appId,
    apiKey: apiKey,
    indexName: 'sprechstunden'
});

var hits_fachbereiche = instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits_fachbereiche',
    hitsPerPage: 100,
    templates: {
        empty: '',
        item: template_fachbereiche
    },
    cssClasses: {
        root: 'group',
        item: 'gridItem fachbereich'
    }
});

var hits_zentren = instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits_zentren',
    hitsPerPage: 100,
    templates: {
        empty: '',
        item: template_zentren
    },
    cssClasses: {
        root: 'group',
        item: 'gridItem zentrum'
    }
});

var hits_experten = instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits_experten',
    hitsPerPage: 100,
    templates: {
        empty: '',
        item: template_experten
    },
    cssClasses: {
        root: 'group',
        item: 'gridItem experte'
    }
});

var hits_sprechstunden = instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits_sprechstunden',
    hitsPerPage: 100,
    templates: {
        empty: '',
        item: template_sprechstunden
    },
    cssClasses: {
        root: 'group',
        item: 'gridItem sprechstunde'
    }
});

fachbereiche.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
        container: '#filter_fachbereiche',
        attributeName: 'facet',
        limit: 100,
        operator: 'and'
    })
);

zentren.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
        container: '#filter_zentren',
        attributeName: 'facet',
        limit: 100,
        operator: 'and'
    })
);

experten.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
        container: '#filter_experten',
        attributeName: 'facet',
        limit: 100,
        operator: 'and'
    })
);

sprechstunden.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
        container: '#filter_sprechstunden',
        attributeName: 'facet',
        limit: 100,
        operator: 'and'
    })
);

var searchbox = instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: document.querySelector('#searchbox'),
    autofocus: false
});

fachbereiche.addWidget(hits_fachbereiche);
fachbereiche.addWidget(searchbox);
zentren.addWidget(hits_zentren);
experten.addWidget(hits_experten);
sprechstunden.addWidget(hits_sprechstunden);

zentren.start();
experten.start();
sprechstunden.start();
fachbereiche.start();

fachbereiche.on('render', function() {
    initMasonry();
});
```

Both MUST have a different container assigned (eg #hits_experten and #hits_sprechstunden). If not, only the first hits widget will be outputted.

Is it somehow possible to just have ONE single container (#hits) for both widgets?

Answer (score 1):

InstantSearch.js v2 addresses this issues with connectors which are the render less counterpart of the widget. You provide a function to the connector and you get a widget factory. There are [more information on the doc](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/connectors.html).

You can also take another approach to this problem. The hits widget being a very simple in terms of business logic, you could reimplement your own:

```
var search = instantsearch(/* options */);
search.addWidget({
  render: function(opts){
    var results = opts.results;
    var hits = results.hits;
    hits.forEach(function(h) {
      // render the hit wherever you want
    });
  }
});
search.start();
```

The documentation of the v2 for [custom widgets](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/guides/custom-widget.html) is relevant for v1.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement your approach. And as far as I can see, this would mean I cannot have different result templates, right? There are 4 or 5 different indices, each of these must have a different template but all of them must have the same hits container. UPDATE: I added the full code in my question.

Comment: Another thought would be to have a different template for each facet. Would that be possible with either v1 or v2?

Comment: With a custom widget you do whatever you want on the rendering. What I meant is that you can reuse the same container (which is not the default behaviour) in your new hit implementation.